# I installed Ubuntu instead of Windows. Where are my files from D drive?

Tags: ubuntu, files, windows

I'm quite new in Linux. I have had a Windows and two drives: `C` and `D`. Windows was on `C`. Then I installed Ubuntu instead of Windows, and I expected my files on `D` will stay. But I can't find it.

As far as I understand, for this purpose I should mount some `sda*`, but with `sudo lsblk` I didn't found any suitable device. I tried to mount all of them with no results. Sorry, I can't provide to you the output of `sudo lsblk`, because it all happened on my friend's laptop, she is far now.

So, is there any chances that files are still existing somewhere?

Comment: You had files on `D` and then installed Ubuntu onto `D`. What options did you select in the installation? The default wipes the drive to perform the installation.

Comment: which option did you use with the installer?

Comment: @Celeo, but there is no Windows anymore, so seems like i installed Ubunto on what was `C` drive in Windows. @Celeo, @Mateo I can't really remember what i chose. It was something default :)

Comment: if you chose the first option everything is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Celeo shared I think you chances are small. What you should have done before installation are two things :-

a. Make a backup of the content on the `D` drive before doing that. 
b. Make `D` partition smaller and then make `E` which is free, blank and has nothing.

Then when you install choose E to install Ubuntu or whichever GNU/Linux distribution you want to do Then you will be able to see your MS-Windows partitions once you have installed the `ntfs-3g driver`

```
$ aptitude show ntfs-3g
Package: ntfs-3g                         
State: installed
Automatically installed: yes
Version: 1:2014.2.15AR.3-1
Priority: optional
Section: otherosfs
Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 1,542 k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libgcrypt20 (>= 1.6.1), libgnutls-deb0-28 (>= 3.3.0), libgpg-error0 (>= 1.14)
PreDepends: multiarch-support, fuse
Provides: libntfs-3g853
Description: read/write NTFS driver for FUSE
 NTFS-3G uses FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) to provide support for the NTFS filesystem used by Microsoft Windows.
Homepage: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/
```

There may be some forensic tools which might help you but as shared by @Celeo it all depends on how you did the installation.

At my end, an NTFS partition :-

```
$ mount | grep Data
/dev/sda5 on /media/shirish/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Actually even fdisk should give you some output, this is from a dual-boot machine :-

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: xxxxxxxxx

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1               63  102398309  102398247  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        102398371 1953523711 1851125341 882.7G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        102398373  204796619  102398247  48.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6  *     204797952  595421183  390623232 186.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7        595423232  790732799  195309568  93.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8        790734848 1943076863 1152342016 549.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       1943078912 1953523711   10444800     5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Even this should give you some output, see that /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda5 are both NTFS partitions.
```

Comment: Thank you! But what about `C`? I thought if i have `C` and `D` I can just install GNU/Linux on `C` partition, and `D` will stay

Comment: But did you do that? If you installed on `C` then the data in `D` should remain. First run update so your distribution is fully updated, then install `ntfs-3g` and see what your graphical file-manager says.

Comment: agh yeah, I will try to install `ntfs-3g`, thanks!

Comment: Please do NOT install ANYTHING. Download and burn "testdisk"   from another computer. See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd  Best results  from testdisk will be when nothing is done after installing the new OS.

Comment: This answer does seem a bit on the spammy side

Comment: @Anatoly, Rinzwind is also right. That would be the best to do, BUT only if you have answered the questions before.

Comment: @shirish yeah well I did assume he did what I have seen a lot on AskUbuntu: pick the "delete windows and install ubuntu" assuming the installer would leave D: alone. By the way: what is stated here can also be achieved with "fdisk" or gparted from a live dvd: NTFS partitions will be listed as such. Installing software and using the operating system will make recovering worse if the partition was formatted.

Comment: @Rinzwind just shared the bit about fdisk as well. You are right in the sense because the more s/he uses, the more s/he will over-write the sectors making recovery difficult if s/he wants to recover data from that portion as well. His/her call really, although the first mantra is always to take backups before doing anything like this.

Comment: @shirish better :) upvoted <3

Comment: Also Ubuntu can natively see any partition without 3rd party tools.

Comment: @Virusboy, oh that's news to me, didn't know that. It's been a few years since I used Ubuntu, have been using Debian for quite sometime. If they do, how do they do that, do you know?

Comment: thanks everybody for the discussion :) I realize that my mistake was not to make a backup. I learn on my mistakes :) I'll try to run `testdisk` and then, if nothing will come out, I'll try `ntfs-3g`

Answer (score -1):

dont select the first option while installing the ubuntu if you want the other drives data